# Find items that are NOT in an list within index items for Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Im using Azure Search

I have the data structure below

```
[
    {
        "id": "7c064374-73ea-4d0c-c363-2801887b07cf",
        "companies": [
                {
                    "companyId": "6f8d235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0",
                    "companyName": "Company"
                }
         ]
    }
]
```

If I want to find all the entries where a guid exists in accounts the filter is

```
$filter=companies/any(c: c/companyId eq 'value to find')
```

What is the syntax for getting only entries where value to find is NOT in the companies list?

```
$filter=companies/any(c: c/companyId ne 'value to find')
```

Will not work because it will return any entries in the index that contain a company id that is not the id which is enough to to bring a entry back if an entry has 2 companies, one that matches the criteria and one that doesnt

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-collection-operators
`$filter=companies/all(c: c/companyId ne 'value to find')`